# Turn underscored names in Rails into 'pretty' text (Like ActiveRecord)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

I have a real simple question here. I only want to know if there is an existing Rails way to accomplish this, because I don't want to re-write something that is already in the framework.

Think of an underscored variable name like "this_is_an_example". Is there a quick way to turn that into "This is an example" or even "This Is An Example" using Rails? I know ActiveRecord prints table column names like "first_name" as "First Name", how is it doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing that already exists is called the Inflector. Check out the documentation at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html.

All the methods listed there are new methods on Strings, so in your case:

```
st = "this_is_an_example"
st.humanize # => "This is an example"
st.titleize # => "This Is An Example"
```

Comment: "this_is_an_example".classify = ThisIsAnExample

Answer (score 2):

ruby script/console 
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)

> > "this_is_an_example".titleize
> >     => "This Is An Example"
> >
> > "this_is_an_example".humanize
> >     => "This is an example"

Answer (score 1):

I should have looked a little harder for a solution before asking.

```
>> string = "an_example_string"
=> "an_example_string"
>> string.titleize
=> "An Example String"
>>
```

Find the docs for this here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M001058